# Student side strategies for handling stressful atmosphere in class

Tags: masters

At first day of second semester of my  M.S biomedical engineering classes we have 12 units as 4  courses:

1. Image Analysis
2. Fuzzy systems

3. Pattern recognition

4. Research methodology

So only the fourth course is with one other master and the 3 others courses are with one master in 2 day as compressed time setting of classes.

After first day, i have seen some conflict between myself and the 9 unit courses master, for example :

- I like to have access to cellphone during class to check additional information and some answer for my questions which is faster to find  by googling them, but banned by master. Also found that the statistics [showing](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://eab.com/insights/daily-briefing/academic-affairs/study-97-of-college-students-are-distracted-by-phones-during-class/&ved=2ahUKEwilotbQrcXnAhVRQxUIHYKTBy8QFjAEegQIDRAX&usg=AOvVaw2At5RNwqfclarC60xat6J9):

  > Around 97% of college students use their phones during class for non-educational purposes, according to a study published last month in Journal of Media Education.
- So when I found some strange aspect of his lessons or specially his off topic remarks during the courses, at this time I become so aggressively and feeling  some force to express it by my communication during class by asking hard question from him which I think is intensified by myself need to accessing to others way of finding information by accessing to internet, which comes back to myself from master by changing Class atmosphere to more stressful by side effect on others student.

One of options in this sense is to be silent which have had some negative effect on me like these:

1. By my vision, become Less Efficiently, which takes other of  my times during days to learn course, which is declared by our master which is I think is one of education goal of our master to learn us to become more independent and learn science by ourself, which I think have agreement on it but I like to know about some others ways to handle it as backup when I can not or don't like do it.
2. Missing the opportunity of communicating during the class to one by master and other student.
3. More negative effect, when this master is one of only three mater of
   this University department as this mater chosen as Supervisor for my final thesis.
4. At this first day of class I have done some partly, become so
   silent and writing my questions and some strange behavior of this
   first contact with my master personal characteristics which founded
   and my  guest of psychological theories  based of them to find out
   where am I and how to reaction during the to one by also tracing my
   reaction to find out what happening during myself  into myself
   Manuscript leaflet, but this way is some times based of guesses and
   I feel needs to be testified by communicating and bad part of it is
   expressing those parts which was like notification or advice from
   my side which are common in my culture especially when we become
   more older by ages ( me 36 and master 48 years old !!!)

So I like to know do you have had this kind of strange experiments by being one master in this situation or as a student ( or I am alone!)?

And result of this kind of relation or situation in your life and academic working area if you like to share here?

Also if possible any suggestion tag to Google about this kind of relation.

Comment: I have students who say they use their smartphones for “research”... Sadly for them I can recognize most of the games they are playing as I have two sons who play the same games. Some of those are about to do resits...

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Generations of students attended lecture without cell phones, yet doing so uniquely harms you?

Comment: Yeah although I don’t ban cell phone they are distracting and this adds stress to students try to focus on the lecture.

Comment: @user111388 speaking for myself this reads like a another “do-you-know-that-I’m-*entitled*-to-my-cell-phone” question.

Answer (score 2):

You raise a number of issues here and so this is only a partial answer. Generally, it is a bad idea to fight with an instructor. They set rules and you are pretty much required to follow them. Hopefully the instructor has reasons behind the rules, but normally they have the authority to enforce them in any case.

So, in the case of having smartphones forbidden there is a simple work-around. Get yourself a pack of index cards and always carry a few to class with you. When something arises that you'd like to look up on the phone, write down a very short note to yourself on a separate card so you don't forget it. Then, immediately after class, do your searches. You can also use the card to write down key ideas from the information you find.

Don't discard these cards. They can be very useful for later study when it comes time for exams and such.

The same cards can be used for other important ideas, making it possible to carry a short summary of important ideas for review whenever you have a spare moment.

---

For more on the index card idea, see [this answer](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/1168/1293) to a question on another site here.

Comment: Most researchers are always to be found with some type of permanent notebook - notes at anytime, late night blinding ideas, odd questions to search etc etc

Comment: @SolarMike, even poets, actually.